# Glob minimatch pattern to get React and Meteor imports in a single group

Tags: reactjs, meteor, glob, minimatch, eslint-plugin-import

I'm trying to setup `eslint-plugin-import` package to order my imports as I want to.

Here is an unordered example:

```
@chakra-ui/react
meteor/meteor
meteor/react-meteor-data
api/templates/collection
react
react-i18next
ui/state/useCsvMappingObject
```

The first group I would like to make is imports starting with `meteor/` and `react`.

So I need to get:

```
meteor/meteor
meteor/react-meteor-data
react
react-i18next
```

I would expect something like `*(meteor/**|react*)` to work, but it doesn't.

`react*` — gives me correct results.

`meteor/**` — too

But I don't understand how to correctly combine them together. Is that possible?